# How to find the custom bounty message after the bounty was awarded?

Tags: support, bounty, data-explorer

In the timeline of a question you can see the generic reason a bounty was awarded (e.g. ["draw attention"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25924548/timeline)) but not the actual message the user offering the bounty has typed in (if any).

Is this info still publicly available somehow, after bounty was awarded?  If so, how to discover it?  I saw a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/631856/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history?questionid=25924548) about this on SEDE but it's returning 0 results.

Comment: Did you switch the site to run the query on to Stack Overflow? Seems to work just fine: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/631856/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history?questionid=25924548

Comment: Ah, I missed that part - thanks, it works. It would be nice to get this info and context added to timeline or revision history directly.

Comment: That query is from [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature request to add the custom bounty message is also posted on the Uber-Meta:

> [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history)

but it didn't make progress beyond the 6 to 8 weeks estimate.

You did find my SEDE query that I also offered as answer on the MSE Question. As noted by Animuson you need to run the query against the database of the site you're looking for that bounty post notice.

The current database is shown in the url and in the right hand side of the page. You can switch to a different database by typing the site name in the switch combo-box. Here is a picture with red freehand circles:

[image: switch sites on SEDE]